# SQL Type Casting: CAST Function versus Explicit Type Functions

Tags: sql

*Given*:

```
SELECT
  CAST('2020-01-01' AS DATE), -- A
  DATE('2020-01-01'),         -- B
  DATE '2020-01-01';          -- C
```

1. Are **B** & **C** equivalent to the standard SQL CAST in **A**? What are the differences?
2. Are **B** & **C** referred to as *explicit type functions*?
3. Are **B** & **C** standard SQL?

Comment: I saw **C** used in *Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL* by Snodgrass, 1999. I don't believe I've encountered it before, which sparked the question. Snodgrass refers to them as constructors.

Comment: A & C are standard ANSI SQL

Answer (score 1):

The first A `CAST` is part of the ANSI-92 standard, [see here](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt).  The B option is vendor specific.  MySQL, for instance, offers a `DATE()` function, which can be used to cast datetime and timestamp inputs to pure date.  The C option uses an ANSI literal, and recent versions of Oracle support this, e.g.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT date '2020-01-01' AS dt FROM dual
)
```

Comment: "*and recent versions of Oracle support this"* - I think that is supported since at least 9i. It's also supported by Postgres and DB2